# External Link in iFrame

Tags: html, ios, iframe

I am embedding an iFrame linking to a html sign-in page of my service within another domain. Works quite fine (the sign-in dialog is shown) but the issue is that my service, if you want to sign in using i.e. Google, wants to forward to google oAuth and then back.
This works quite fine on the Desktop Browser, however, tested on iOS Browser, the click on the link does simply nothing.

Weird fact is that, when holding down and clicking "open link in new tab" on iOS, everything works as expected, my service routes to google, I can login and then the cookie is set so I can see my app.

Is there anything I might be missing special to iOS?
Note that cross-origin iFrame linking to *my* service in the iFrame works just fine..

thanks
Alex

Comment: Are you trying to show Google’s AOuth inside of the iframe as well? They don’t want that, of course – because the user has to see the URL of the login to prevent phishing – and therefore they prevent it.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. However, this works just fine on a Desktop Browser but not on iOS